# How to update app via Xcode 5.1.1 for iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app in App Store that was build using Xcode 5.1.1. Is there a way for me to update the the app via the same Xcode version? Because when i tried to use Xcode 6.4 the app produced crashes.  I have seen in iTunes connect that we can upload app via Xcode 5.1.1. The app compiled using Xcode 5.1.1 is working perfectly in iOS 9 though.

Comment: You should bite the bullet and upgrade Xcode.  The crashes *may* be caused by iOS (SDK), but it's far more likely that your app is doing something wrong that it used to get away with, but no longer can.

Comment: Okay. The app compiled using Xcode 5.1.1 is working perfectly in iOS 9.

Comment: @Dony : that is because Xcode 5.1.1 is using iOS 8 and not iOS 9... So you have code that make crashes if you compile with iOS 9 and you will need to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

The application will still produce crashs because you are not using the latest SDK.

So for iOS 9 it will not run properly , as you might use some deprecated methods which will cause crashs.

The proper way is to use the latest xCode, especially for testing purpose ..so you will be sure that your app will work properly with the latest iOS.

Comment: Whatever the crashes are, it's unlikely that *not* compiling against iOS9 SDK is the cause.  If anything, the crashes only occur when compiling against iOS8+ (which Xcode 6.4 ships with).

Comment: Okay. The app compiled using Xcode 5.1.1 is working perfectly in iOS 9

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an app ready for iOS 9 you need to create/test the build using iOS9 sdk which is only available with xcode 7.0 and above. So you may update the app via xcode 5.1.1 but that won't be considered ready for iOS9.